# BIND 9 intermittently slow

Tags: dns, performance, bind

I'm running several Bind servers (v9.10.4) to provide DNS services to my users.  Intermittently (about 30 seconds every 15 minutes) all recursive requests will fail and timeout.  CPU and Memory on all the servers are in normal ranges and no errors are being logged on the servers.  Does anyone have good tricks on tracking down Bind performance issues?

My problem is similar to the one described at [BIND/DNSMASQ query hanging on ubuntu server 14.04.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176560/bind-dnsmasq-query-hanging-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-1) but the solution there didn't help me.

EDIT 2017-08-29:

Here's my redacted `named.conf` file if it's helpful.  The `slave.conf` file that's included on the last line is just a file with a bunch of zone definitions in it.

```
acl "trusted" {
    ** redacted **
};

options {
        directory "/var/bind";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";

        allow-query { trusted; };
        allow-query-cache { trusted; };
        allow-recursion { trusted; };
        allow-transfer { none; };
        allow-update { none; };

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation auto;
};

include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";
controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 port 953 allow { 127.0.0.1/32; ::1/128; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

zone "." in {
        type hint;
        file "/var/bind/named.cache";
};

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "pri/localhost.zone";
        notify no;
};

include "/etc/bind/slave.conf";
```

Comment: Have you managed to fix this?

Comment: Not really.  I discovered that having logging turned up too much (like you would have it when you're having problems) can cause problems for Bind.  I turned logging off and tripled the number of servers handling those requests.  It's better now but I don't think I really solved the ultimate issue.

Comment: Hmmm odd. Have you raised the number of default clients?

Comment: (i also have high logging, but that is an entirely different talk. BIND ought to be simple, had many servers and never had issues I could not solve) Are you sure it is not firewall or infra-structure limitations?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the number of default clients.  I can't find a client limit anywhere in the documentation.  I've edited the question to include my named.conf if it's helpful.

Comment: under options `recursive-clients 30000`; for instance - that was one of my biggest rookie mistakes when I started using BIND in an ISP setting ; I think you are hitting the built-in limit of 1000. The details are fuzzy in my mind, but you ought to have logs about that.

Comment: Interesting.  That never showed up in my logs (I've long since deleted them but something about rate limiting would have been a massive red flag).  Thanks for the tip.  I'll give it a shot

Comment: Let me know if it worked, I might have a couple extra tips to add to the answer.

Comment: Since I tripped the number of servers answering requests I haven't had any complaints which would seem to suggest it was hitting some kind of limit.  I'm reluctant to cut back on servers just to test if this solves it because if it doesn't then I've subjected my people to bad Internet just to test a theory.  I'm going to to with 1) it hasn't broken anything and 2) it's probably good practice to include and leave it at that.  Thanks

Comment: that was supposed to be 'tripled' not 'tripped' :)

Comment: It might still bit you in a contigency though. Maybe generating requests in one test server?

Comment: btw, which distro?

Comment: Gentoo, but it happens when I install from their repos and when I pull down the source and build it myself.